# How to read xml in anchor tags of html page

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml

How can I read XML file on html page. 
i want my XML link value to go in anchor 
tags href attribute and Name of the website
between the anchor tags

I just know very basic Javascript.

I am trying to change value in footer of my website using XML because i have more than 100 pages and every time I change something in footer I have to change all 100 pages manually that's why i want to change the footer links through XML.

Please explain by showing code page should look like this

```
<div>
   <a href "this value should be read by xml">and this value should also be read by xml</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it have to be XML? If you use jQuery and put your href in an external html file you could just use the load() function http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: XML is just a data format, and has nothing to do with changing 100 pages etc. You should be using a serverside language to include the footer on every page, that way you can change the footer once, and it will update on all the pages.

Comment: Agreed, adeneo.  Arvind: try looking at this to see if it's the kind of thing you have in mind: http://www.mediatitan.com/articles/php_server_side_includes.php

Comment: Guys thanks for answers but website is made on html and now cant change to any sever side language and its not hard and fast to use only xml you can suggest other alternatives also.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your answers but after a lot of search i found exactly what i wanted. I wanted to change multiple pages footer section using single file without changing my pages name (from .html pages to other like .aspx,.php,.asp) I thought using xml would be a good way but i am really novice in this field and xml didnt work for me (or say i am unable to use it in proper way) therefore i found out an alternative to change to content of multiple html pages using single file. All i needed to do was use SSI aka server side includes. The only thing you need to do is check if your server supports SSI or not and then make an individual html footer page that you want to include on every page. In order to include that external footer page just type.

```
<!--#include file="footer.html" -->
```

in the area,div,table wherever you want your footer to load and its done .

For detailed article pls go to following link http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html